# Can't make langid work in Solr 4.0

Tags: solr

I just installed Solr, and I'm now experimenting to learn how to use it. I'd like to use [Solr Cell](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) and [langid](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) features, so I followed the linked tutorials. Solr Cell works, but I can't get langid to do anything.

In `solrconfig.xml`, I have this:

```xml
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="langid">
  <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="langid.fl">text,title,subject,description</str>
    <str name="langid.langField">language_s</str>
    <str name="langid.fallback">en</str>
    <bool name="langid.map">true</bool>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

(I also tried with Tika), and I send a document using

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=test&commit=true" -F "myfile=@test.xml"
```

But when I query, `text:[* TO *]` gives me back my document, but `text_en:[* TO *]` doesn't; `language_s`, even if I declare it as stored, is stubbornly absent; `*:word` doesn't find anything even though there's `"words"` so it's not getting stemmed; and I can't find anything in the log. My best guess is, langid doesn't run, and I have no idea why.

**EDIT**: Found the answer: [read more docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor#Selecting_the_UpdateChain_for_Your_Request) :p

Since langid is configured as an update request processor chain, it needs to get selected (it's not automatic). So, this works:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=test&commit=true&update.chain=langid" -F "myfile=@test.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that, had the same trouble. P.S in my case (latest SOLR), the update url was -Durl="http://localhost:8080/solr/update?update.chain=langid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: [read more docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor#Selecting_the_UpdateChain_for_Your_Request) :p

Since langid is configured as an update request processor chain, it needs to get selected (it's not automatic). So, this works:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=test&commit=true&update.chain=langid" -F "myfile=@test.xml"
```